# Tweepy DM methods do not return DMS

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, python-twitter

Title says it all.

If I use 
`print(api.list_direct_messages(count = 20))`, 
the result is just `[]`, despite receiving many DMs.

`get.direct.message(id)` has also not worked, since I haven't figured out how to find the ID of a specific direct message.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One reason you may be getting an an empty list returned is, your messages may be older than 30 days. Tha API only returns messages, both sent and received less than 30 days old. I covered a workaround for getting ID's of tweets here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603493/get-latest-direct-message-from-twitter-using-python-tweepy/61550715#61550715

Comment: I get a lot of DMs, so that isn't the problem, thank you though.